# Trying to update records in database with Entity Framework and using two keys from another list of object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0

So I'm passing in a list of objects (that are originally in the database already) to a function to update a property (SentDate) in the database, the structure is similar to

```
public class Product
{
  [Key, Column("SKU", Order = 0)]
  public string SKU { get; set; }
  [Key, Column("Sequence", Order = 1)]
  public int Sequence { get; set; }
  public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
}
```

And it is going into a function to update. Where I went wrong was I was attempting to do:

```
public static void UpdateSentDate(List<Product> records, DateTime CurrentDate)
{
  DbContext db = new DbContext(); // there is a DbSet for Product in here
  var toUpdate = db.Products.Where(c => records.Contains(c)).ToList();
  foreach (var rec in toUpdate)
  {
    rec.SentDate = CurrentDate;
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This bombs at the toUpdate creation due to the records.Contains(c) as it doesn't involve primitives. So I'm curious how to get the records where records's SKUs and Sequences match up with the database's that is better than my current stopgap:

```
List<Product> dbRecords = new List<Product>();
foreach (var record in records)
{
  var item = db.Products.Where(c => c.SKU == record.SKU && c.Sequence == record.Sequence).Single();
  dbRecords.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it work a little faster if you assign  a new date in the same time

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
  var item = db.Products.Where(c => c.SKU == record.SKU && c.Sequence == record.Sequence).Single();
  if (item!=null)
  {
   item.SentDate = CurrentDate;
   db.Entry(item).Property(i=>i.SentDate).IsModified = true; // maybe you can ommit this
  }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```